# Index on String(varchar2) column vs Index on Number column

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle

Would data type affect the performance of querying a indexed column?

For example:

`table1(id, phone_no(varchar2(20), name, address)`

table2(id, phone_no(number(20), name, address)

Say both table contains same data.

Now if I query based on phone_no, would performance be different or same? Why?

Note: Above is just an example. It may not be great idea to store phone_no as number.

Comment: The question has no relevance, really. You choose the data type for the column based on the data that it contains. If you stored a value in the wrong data type then there would be many problems more serious than index performance.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, what if you have freedom to decide between two data types?

Comment: You always have that freedom, but I've never seen a case where there wasn't a clear correct choice. If it is valid to perform arithmetic operations on the value, then it is a number. If it is not, then it's a string that can only be composed of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance is a very complex topic...
Regardless of the fact that you have a VARCHAR2 or a NUMBER column, performance may depend - just for example - if you have an Index on your column.
The Index may (or may not) be used, depending on updated or stale statistics, depending on how many records match your WHERE condition (it's more correct to talk about how many blocks are visited by the query: even with a small percentage of rows retrieved, the optimizer may choose a FULL TABLE SCAN if you have your records distributed across many blocks!) and so on...

From the space/storage point of view, for a NUMBER(20,0) Oracle will allocate 12 bytes. But for a VARCHAR2(20) it depends on the length of your data (up to 20 bytes).

Comment: "for a NUMBER(20,0) Oracle will allocate 12 bytes" ... not really the case. The storage requirement depends on the number of significant digits stored, so storing 1,000,000,000 requires only 2 bytes. 1 byte to store the exponent, 1 byte for every two significant digits of the mantissa (rounded up of course). http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1833

Comment: I wrongly considered the maximum number only, vsize(99999999999999999999), that takes 11 bytes, plus 1 byte for the exponent. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of performance, you should **not** store phone number as a number/integer. It's not a number. You can't add or multiply two phone numbers. Store it as a string.

That being said, I would expect integers to perform slightly better (because of taking up less memory, for example)

Comment: Well, I am working for a mobile phone operator and a phone number is definitely a **nubmer**, so I would store it as integer number. Storing them as string goes into same direction as storing a date as string. Consider postal codes, which are also numeric (in most countries) but it also does not make any sense to add or multiply two postal codes.

Comment: @Wernfried: You can, however, subtract two dates and get a meaningful result. This is not the case of phone numbers. A phone number has really only one meaningful operation: equality comparison. You can't even tell if one number is "greater" than another.

Comment: And yes, postal code is not a number too, it's a string. Think about leading zeroes, for example, "005521123456"

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, regarding equality comparison: If you like to compare for example "0800 555 12 43" and "08005551243" the number storge seems to be more suitable. A phone number can do much more than just comparison, see [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164). But maybe this is getting too technical for this platform here.

Comment: @Wernfried, just because you call them phone "numbers" doesn't mean they are numbers. `+614920840` is a phone "number", but it is not a "number" in a mathematical, or indeed a computing sense. It is a string of digits.

Comment: The "+" does not belong to a phone number, it's just a. formatting item. But as I wrote already, this is very specific detail.

Comment: The reason doesn't really apply. IDs don't have arithmetic operations either, but they are integers.

Comment: @Fifnmar: if you're talking about auto-incrementing primary key sequences, then it's the DB that does arithmetic operations on them. More precisely, it takes the last number and adds 1 to it. But not all ids are integers. I tend to use UUIDs or strings.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I agree on your idea of not using Number Types for data that the business do no arithmetic operations on, because the data, in the end, are going to be sent to frontend through text protocols.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: (continued) However, for data that is used for internal calculation, not only IDs, it's better to choose what is the most machine-friendly.